# Error installing the composer-cli on ubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-composer

I received the following error when attempting to install the composer-cli on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.4

`Failed at the hashtable@2.0.2 install script 'node-gyp configure build'`

current versions:

- npm v3.10.10
- node v6.10.0

if it matters:

- docker v1.12.5
- docker-compose v1.10.0

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by installing python with the following command:

`$ sudo apt-get install python-pip`